# Prevent group ownership change on file save?

Tags: permissions, 14.04

For any given file in the web root, the permissions are initially set to `me:www-data` with `chmod 750`. Opening a file in an editor and saving via the editors `save` command changes the group to `me:me`. How do I prevent group changes on save?

Comment: @WarrenHill: this is a completely different question...

Answer (score 1):

Linux saves the file using your active group, so change your active group before you edit.

Easiest method is to change your primary group.

You can do this temporarily with `newgrp` , this command starts a new shell

```
newgrp www-data
gedit your_file
exit
```

If you want to change your primary group permanently, use `usermod`

```
usermod -g www-data your_user
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug (LP [#199167](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/199167)).

You could try to open your editor as `www-data` using `gksudo -u www-data gedit`.

Comment: It may be related to that bug... but that's a really old bug! Opening as `www-data` wouldn't help because `www-data` should not have write permissions to the files for security reasons.